# how to handle errors using python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, jenkins

I am comparing two files in my program below. If it is same then I am printing as success else as failure. I am using a integrating tool called jenkins to send an email when it is failure in comparing the files, to do this - I have to handle the error properly. Can someone tell me how to handle the error ?

```
Error_Status=0
def compare_files(file1, file2):
   try:
       with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
           if f_file1.read() == f_file2.read():
               print 'SUCCESS \n'
               #print 'SUCESS:\n  {}\n  {}'.format(file1, file2)
           else:
               print 'FAILURE \n'
               Error_Status=1
    except IOError:
        print "File is NOT compared"
        Error_Status = 1
```

jenkins console output :

```
E:\Projekte\Audi\Cloud_SOP17_TTS>rem !BUILD step: Execute test: tts.py 

E:\Projekte\Audi\Cloud_SOP17_TTS>call python tts.py file1 file2   || echo failed 
INPUT ENG: I am tired
Latency: 114msec



[ERROR] Can't Create Reference PCM or Response JSON files!
INPUT GED: facebook nachricht schÃ¶nes wetter heute
Latency: 67msec
INPUT GED: erinnere mich an den termin heute abend
Latency: 113msec

E:\Projekte\Audi\Cloud_SOP17_TTS>echo Started at: 15:51:25.37 
Started at: 15:51:25.37

E:\Projekte\Audi\Cloud_SOP17_TTS>exit 0 
Archiving artifacts
Recording plot data
Saving plot series data from: E:\Projekte\Audi\Cloud_SOP17_TTS\Backups\tts_2016_02_04.py
Not creating point with null values: y=null label= url=
No emails were triggered.
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Comment: How are you calling this script from Jenkins? You could `exit` with a non-standard exit code, or maybe raise an exception. Or compare the files in a different way, using bash commands instead of Python.

Comment: You could just use `diff`. If the files are the same, the exit code is `0`, if they are different, the exit code is `1`. Use `$?` to get the exit code.

Comment: I have the workspace, I copied my code there. I scheduled to run my code for every one hour. I used just exit in my code below print 'FAILURE' but it not handling.

Comment: This will be a memory hog if they are large files (you read the complete file in).  Why reinvent the wheel?  As @tobias_k suggests, use `diff` or `cmp`

Comment: @tobias:can you please tell me how ?

Comment: have you tried except ? To check what exactly the error is.

Comment: i changed my code, you can see now

Answer (score 2):

It is not really necessary to write your own code to do this, because you will just be reimplementing the existing [`cmp(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cmp) Unix command, or the [`fc`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722865.aspx#XSLTsection124121120120) command if you are using Windows.

You can do one of the following in your Jenkins workspace:

```
# UNIX shell
cmp file1 file2 || send email
```

I'm not au fait with Windows scripting, but something like this should work:

```
rem Windows batch file
FC /B file1 file2
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 SEND_EMAIL_COMMAND
```

---

If you really want your own Python script to do this.....

Jenkins will execute your script from within a shell (or similar command interpreter). To communicate the result of the comparison you can set the process' exit status using `sys.exit()`. The convention is that a command was successful if it's exit status is 0, otherwise it failed, so you could use 0 when the files are the same, and 1 when they are not (or there was an error).

```
import sys

def compare_files(file1, file2):
    try:
        with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
            return f_file1.read() == f_file2.read()
    except Exception as exc:
        print 'compare_files(): failed to compare file {} to {}: {}'.format(file1, file2, exc)
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) >= 3:
       if not compare_files(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]):
           sys.exit(1)
    else:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'Usage: {} file1 file2'.format(sys.argv[0])
        sys.exit(2)
```

Then in your Jenkins workspace:

```
python compare_files.py file1 file2 || send email
```

or

```
call python compare_files.py file1 file2
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 SEND_EMAIL_COMMAND
```

Comment: I am comparing these two files, compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename). how to adapt in your code ? I did if not compare_files(ref_filename, cur_filename) in your code but it is not working.

Comment: @sam: my code expects the 2 files to be supplied on the command line. These are passed verbatim to the `compare_files()` function. I assume that you are running a command similar to `python compare_files.py file1 file2` in your Jenkins workspace. You don't have to adapt anything... just try running the script, or even better, just use `cmp file1 file2`.

Comment: its not working for me. is that working on your side ?

Comment: @sam: what exactly does "it's not working" mean? It does work for me. Just run the script.... `python compare_files.py file1 file2 || echo failed`.

Comment: this is the console output I am getting in jenkins can be seen above.

Comment: @sam: You are using windows. In my answer error handling (with `||`) assumes a UNIX shell. I have updated my answer with some a way to do it in Windows, however, I'm not able to test it.

Comment: I did as you said but it is not working when it fails.

Comment: @sam: I don't know what else to advise you. Perhaps you are out of your depth with this task and you need to learn more about the scripting environment that you are using with Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare line by line using `all` and `izip_longest` so you won't have two whole files in memory at once and return any [`errno`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/errno.html) when an error is raised:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

def compare_files(file1, file2):
    try:
        with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
            return all(l1 == l2 for l1, l2 in izip_longest(f_file1, f_file2, fillvalue=""))
    except EnvironmentError  as e:
        print("File is NOT compared, error message {}".format(e))
        return e.errno
```

Any number bar 0 or 1 will mean an error was raised.

```
In [4]: compare_files("same1.txt","same2.txt")
Out[4]: True

In [5]: compare_files("foo","bar")
File is NOT compared,error message [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'foo'
Out[5]: 13
In [6]: compare_files("test1","test2")
File is NOT compared,error message [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'foo'
Out[6]: 21
In [7]: compare_files("does_not_exist.txt","foo")
File is NOT compared,error message [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'does_not_exist.txt'
Out[7]: 2
In [8]: compare_files("log.txt","out.txt")
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: comparing is nothing but reading the content of the file. I have binary data in the files and I am comparing that.

Comment: @sam, what is inside is irrelevant, this will work regardless and return the correct error code on any error.

Answer (score -1):

Use `assert`. It will exit throwing an exception, so you will get the traceback will be written to the output and the Jenkins task will fail.

```
def compare_files(file1, file2):
    with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
        assert f_file1.read() == f_file2.read()
```

I don't see the point in catching exceptions if the goal is exactly to see what went wrong and make the Jenkins job fail.

**EDIT:** If you really want to print SUCCESS of FAILURE explicitly:

```
def compare_files(file1, file2):
    try:
        with open(file1, 'rb') as f_file1, open(file2, 'rb') as f_file2:
            assert f_file1.read() == f_file2.read()
    except:
        '''
        I know, I know. Normally we should catch specific exceptions.
        But OP wants to print SUCCESS or FAILURE and fail the Jenkins job
        in case of error.
        '''
        print 'FAILURE'
        raise
    else:
        print 'SUCCESS'
```

Comment: but I want to print Success or Failure. how to do that ?

Comment: Jenkins will do that for you. If task fails the last line of Jenkins console output is `Finished: FAILURE` and `Finished: SUCCESS` otherwise.

Comment: @sam If Jenkins is not printing it then probably you have misconfigured the task. Check the edited answer anyway...